Firefox only- Fetch GET (JSON) shows "NS_BINDING_ABORTED" with Service-Worker
I am using a Service Worker to serve cached data (1st time loading from server, then loading from Cache if same request).
A GET Fetch request to my server returns valid JSON data.
On second Page load, the data is taken from the Service-Worker-Cache which fails (only in Firefox).
-> The data is incomplete (JSON is trimmed) and there is an error "NS_BINDING_ABORTED".
How do I debug this?

Screenshot of Firefox inspector showing the failed request


Screenshot shows cut-off JSON data:



